# Retrieve and post data to another url

Tags: php, post, get, http-post

Hi i'm facing error with the following code below

```
    if(isset($_POST['get4']))
{
$pid = $_POST['get4'];
```

Currently want to implement is that i want to retrieve the get4 object & post the data to another url im.php

i tried this code

```
            if(isset($_POST['get4']))
    {
    $pid = $_POST['get4'];
    $_POST;$url=http://xyz . com/im.php
}
```

but not working .any answers?

Comment: Please provide some more context for your question. You didn't even close your `if` statement.

Comment: please provide the full code along with html.

Comment: Please add more code for your question/problem.

Comment: You can check out now what's my error i have edited

Comment: You have provided 3 lines of code. If you want people to help you trouble shoot the problem you'll want to include a SSCCE so we can take a look at it and find the real problem. There just isn't enough there for anybody to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to send that variable to another page using **`GET`** , you can simply do like this..

```
if(isset($_POST['get4']))
{
$pid = $_POST['get4'];
}
header("location:yourpage.php?pid=$pid");
```

**yourpage.php**

```
if(isset($_GET['pid']))
{
echo $new_pid = $_GET['pid'];
}
```

(or)

If you are looking to send that variable using **`POST`** , Make use of **`cURL`**

**EDIT :**

```
if(isset($_POST['get4']))
{
$pid = $_POST['get4'];
}

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "yourpage.php");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"pid=$pid"); //P5435
$response = curl_exec($curl);
echo $response;
```

Comment: Sorry but i only want to use the POST method can u solve it out ??